# Syncing folder with Windows guest in Vagrant and using with IIS

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I'm running a Windows 2012 R2 eval box (`mwrock/Windows2012R2`) on Mac OS Sierra host.

I'm trying to setup `IIS` to run a web site from the synced folder, but I keep getting an `HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error`.

After researching, I found out that it seems to be related to permissions. I tried every possible combination of permissions, granting to Users, IIS_IUSRS, vagrant, etc., changing the app pool user, etc., nothing got it working.

Then I figured I could just use rsync. So I tried to change my Vagrantfile to use type: `rsync`, and then got an error saying `rsync` was not found in the `PATH`.

No problem, I installed `rsync` using chocolatey and tried again. This time, I got an SSH error: `Error: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`. I figured there probably wasn't anything setup for SSH on Windows guest, so I found [this post on setting up OpenSSH](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server) .

I followed the instructions and tried again. `rsync` still wouldn't work, but now there's no error, it just stalls. I tested just doing a regular SSH to the windows guest and that works fine. However, while doing plain old ssh works, doing vagrant ssh does not.

I get the following error after entering password: `ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 127.0.0.1 port 2222: incomplete message`. Meanwhile, doing `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222` works fine. So running out of ideas at this point.

Anybody manage to get this working with a setup similar to mine?